# MessageboxW in Python ctypes An error ocurred PyEval_RestoreThread

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I create a Messagebox in Python using:

```
import tkinter
import ctypes

class app:

    def __init__(self):
        self._root= tkinter.Tk()
        self._root.grid()
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self._root)
        self.filemenu  = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar) 
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Salva", command=self._save)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="prova", command=self._save)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu) 
        self._root.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def _save(self):
        MBW=ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Salvare le modifiche?", "Salva", 3)

    def mostra(self):
        self._root.mainloop()
a=app()
a.mostra()
```

The error is reproduced by clicking `File, Salva` to open the dialog, then selecting `File, prova` while the dialog is open:

```
C:\>python test.py
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

Current thread 0x00001f70 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\test.py", line 16 in _save
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
  File "C:\test.py", line 19 in mostra
  File "C:\test.py", line 21 in <module>
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent accessing additional menu commands while the dialog is open, pass the handle to the active window `MessageBoxW`, which prevents further interaction with the main window until the dialog is resolved:

```
def _save(self):
    hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.GetActiveWindow()
    MBW = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(hwnd, "Salvare le modifiche?", "Salva", 3)
```

Alternatively, use one of the [tkinter messageboxes](https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html#messages) which internally do the same thing:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

def _save(self):
    answer = messagebox.askyesnocancel("Salvare le modifiche?", "Salva")
```